# How to sequentially execute a "Completable" followed by "Single"?

Tags: rx-java2

I have two reactive methods in "Layer A" that's exposed to the app:

**LAYER A** - publicly accessible methods to the rest of the app

```
public Single<ResponseData> postMyData(ReqData data, Long id) {
    if (!isUserLoggedIn()) return postLogin().andThen(postData(data, id));
    return postData(data, id);
}

public Completable postLogin() {
    Account account = getAccountData();
    ReqLoginData loginData = new ReqLoginData(account.email, account.pass, OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);

    Single<ResponseLogin> singlePostLogin = postLogin(loginData);

    return Completable.create(subscriber -> singlePostLogin.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(loginResponse -> {
                        // Success
                        storeAccessToken(loginResponse);// *** this will recreate apiClient with new access token
                        if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onComplete();
                    }, throwable -> { if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(throwable);}
            ));
}
```

**LAYER B** - only accessible by Layer A

```
public Single<ResponseLogin> postLogin(ReqLoginData loginData) {
    Log.d(TAG, "using apiClient "+apiClient.toString());
    Single<Response<ResponseLogin>> postLogin = apiClient.postLogin(loginData);

    return Single.create(subscriber -> postLogin.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if(response.body() != null) {
                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onSuccess(response.body());
                } else {
                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(new Throwable(response.message()));
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                if(!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(throwable);
            }));
}

public Single<ResponseData> postData(ReqData data, Long id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "using apiClient "+apiClient.toString());
    Single<Response<ResponseData>> postData = apiClient.postData(id, data);

    return Single.create(subscriber -> postData.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if(response.body() != null) {
                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onSuccess(response.body());
                } else {
                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(new Throwable(response.message()));
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                if(!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(throwable);
            }));
}
```

**LAYER C** - API Interface

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST(Constants.API_PREFIX + "/auth/token/")
Single<Response<ResponseLogin>> postLogin(@Body ReqLoginData reqLoginData);

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST(Constants.API_PREFIX + "/data/{id}/")
Single<Response<ResponseData>> postData(@Path("id") Long id, @Body ReqData reqData);
```

A huge challenge for me at the moment is to make sure the user is logged-in before attempting to POST data. So, using `postLogin().andThen(postData(data, id))` made sense to me :

At the time of my late-night development, it seemed that both methods `postLogin()` and `postData()` are called in parallel - with `postLogin()` first.

How can I make `postMyData()` execute `postLogin()` first, wait for success or failure, followed by `postData()` on success ?

**Note:** postLogin() will update `apiClient` with the new token inside storeAccessToken(). I now see that postData() doesn't use a reference to the new `apiClient`. It's important that postData() will use the new `apiClient` that's instantiated within storeAccessToken()

Sorry for the newbie question  :-(

Comment: Where does this `Single.create(subscriber -> someSinge.subscribe())` pattern come from?

Comment: `andThen` is supposed to be the correct answer unless `postData(data, id)` executes the network action immediately and not in response to subscription. Please provide the implementation of `postData(data, id)`.

Comment: @akarnokd please see the above edit. This programming pattern - it's basically what I've been able to piece together after quite a lot of time of online research... I've been to so many webpages, I don't remember the exact page; probably from SO when someone posted they wanted to intercept the result of an API call.

Comment: What do you mean by "both methods postLogin() and postData() are called in parallel "? Your code calls those methods which then prepare `Single`s.

Comment: I've made some extensive edits to my question to illustrate the scenario better. After I read your statement `methods which then prepare Single`, a lightbulb went off and I realized that the code outside of the `Single.create()` is triggered almost in parallel. It was at the end of a 16 hour day - now discussing it is helping me understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that `Completable.andThen(Single)` works very well to serialize code execution. Unfortunately, I didn't (half asleep) realize that only code within the `create()` method was actually scheduled.

my code below answers the problem I had (these are both in **LAYER-B**):

```
public Single<ResponseLogin> postLogin(ReqLoginData loginData) {

    return Single.create(subscriber -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "using apiClient "+apiClient.toString());
        apiClient.postLogin(loginData)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(response -> {
                    if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onSuccess(response.body());
                    } else {
                        if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(new Throwable(response.message()));
                    }
                }, throwable -> {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    if(!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(throwable);
                });
    });
}


public Single<ResponseData> postData(ReqData data, Long id) {

    return Single.create(subscriber -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "using apiClient "+apiClient.toString());
        apiClient.postData(id, data)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if(response.body() != null) {
                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onSuccess(response.body());
                } else {
                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(new Throwable(response.message()));
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                if(!subscriber.isDisposed()) subscriber.onError(throwable);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use this create pattern as you could return the postData+subscribeOn+observeOn from the method itself. RxJava will correctly wire up the cancellation of the network call and act on it properly. At most, you could wrap the flow with `Single.defer(() -> postData().subscribeOn().observeOn())` so that the preparation runs only when there is an end-subscriber.